# Puede una variable de entorno con valor "a" ser distinto a un string "a" en NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, variables-de-configuración, .env

Tengo un problema en NodeJs al crear una variable de entorno sea a través del package.json o por medio de dotenv, en cualquiera de los dos puedo tener una variable "NODE_ENV" con valor "development", a la hora de traer el valor -> process.env.NODE_ENV y compararlo con un string "development", este considera que no son iguales, en este caso con un if.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usa `set NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon server.js` (Sin espacio entre la palabra "development" y "&&"

Comment: Muchas gracias Pipe.

Comment: Pipe aun sigue igual "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon server.js" me devuelve falso en la condicion.

Comment: Probé usando JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) y me da "development " con un espacio a lo ultimo, yo resolvería el problema validando con ese espacio, pero no es un comportamiento común, sabrás que lo provoca?

Comment: si reiniciaste el nodemon antes de volver a probar mi solucion? porque sino no coge las nuevas variables de entorno...

Comment: Pipe, mil gracias, no sabía que nodemon se quedaba con las variables de entorno al iniciar.